# Transform CSV file into a 'flat file" for pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I have CSV files that don't contain a header and each row contains only 2 columns (time & data name) that always has data, the rest of the rows are have a varying number of columns depending on the data.

I've successfully imported "normal" CSV files into pandas that have a consistent number of columns.  It works really well but I have seen anything in the docs to handle this current situation.

**Here's a snippet of the CSV file in question**:

```
1573081480.942000, /eeg, 843.3333, 854.61536, 851.79486, 849.3773, 863.0769
1573081480.942000, /eeg, 844.1392, 857.4359, 849.3773, 861.8681, 890.07324
1573081480.943000, /eeg, 853.8095, 853.8095, 850.989, 866.30035, 854.61536
1573081480.944000, /eeg, 855.42126, 855.0183, 846.1539, 852.1978, 846.9597
1573081480.947000, /eeg, 844.1392, 853.8095, 846.55676, 842.52747, 873.5531
1573081480.947000, /eeg, 848.97437, 853.00366, 851.79486, 853.00366, 856.2271
1573081480.948000, /eeg, 859.0476, 852.6007, 850.18317, 863.8828, 826.0073
1573081480.950000, /eeg, 859.0476, 851.79486, 853.00366, 866.30035, 819.5604
1573081480.950000, /eeg, 851.79486, 852.1978, 846.9597, 854.61536, 859.45056
1573081480.951000, /eeg, 856.63007, 853.00366, 846.55676, 840.9158, 854.21246
1573081480.960000, /elements/alpha_absolute, 0.48463312
1573081480.960000, /elements/beta_absolute, 0.061746284
1573081480.961000, /elements/gamma_absolute, 0.7263172
1573081480.961000, /elements/theta_absolute, 0.7263172
1573081480.961000, /elements/delta_absolute, 0.7263172
```

**The result I need looks something like this**

```
time, eeg_0, eeg_1, eeg_2, eeg_3, delta, theta, alpha, beta, gamma  
1573081480.942000, 844.1392, 857.4359, 849.3773, 861.8681,,,,,  
1573081480.947000, 844.1392, 853.8095, 846.55676, 842.52747, 873.5531,,,,,  
1573081480.947000, 848.97437, 853.00366, 851.79486, 853.00366, 856.2271,,,,,  
1573081480.948000, 859.0476, 852.6007, 850.18317, 863.8828, 826.0073,,,,,  
1573081480.960000,,,,,,,0.48463312,,  
1573081480.960000,,,,,,,,0.061746284,  
1573081480.961000,,,,,0.7263172,,,,  
1573081480.961000,,,,,0.52961296,,,  
1573081480.962000,,,,,,,,-0.26484978
```

As you can see the number of values can change depending on the data that's being stored.

I would like the import process to be as simple and as efficient as with "normal" CSV files.

This is what I was hoping to avoid, it's drearily verbose and inefficient:

```
d = {
    'time': [0.], 
    'eeg0': [0.],'eeg1': [0.],'eeg2': [0.],'eeg3': [0.],'eeg4': [0.], 
    'delta_absolute': [0.], 'theta_absolute': [0], 'alpha_absolute': [0], 'beta_absolute': [0], 'alpha_absolute': [0],
    'acc0': [0], 'acc1': [0], 'acc2': [0], 'gyro0': [0], 'gyro1': [0], 'gyro2': [0], 
    'concentration': [0],'mellow': [0] 
      }

df_new_data = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

csvfile = open(fname) 
csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
csv_data = list(csv_reader)
row_count = len(csv_data)

for row in csv_data:
    if row[1] == ' /muse/acc':
        df_new_data = df_new_data.append({'acc0' : row[2], 'acc1' : row[3], 'acc2' : row[4]}, ignore_index=True)
    if row[1] == ' /muse/gyro':
        df_new_data = df_new_data.append({'gyro0' : row[2], 'gyro1' : row[3], 'gyro2' : row[4]}, ignore_index=True)
```

**EDIT:**

I've found that if the first line of the CSV file contains fewer fields the any subsequent lines then read_csv() will fail. The above example of CSV data works, but this one doesn't:

```
573081480.960000, /elements/alpha_absolute, 0.48463312
1573081480.960000, /elements/beta_absolute, 0.061746284
1573081480.961000, /elements/gamma_absolute, 0.7263172
1573081480.961000, /elements/theta_absolute, 0.7263172
1573081480.961000, /elements/delta_absolute, 0.7263172
1573081480.942000, /eeg, 843.3333, 854.61536, 851.79486, 849.3773, 863.0769
1573081480.942000, /eeg, 844.1392, 857.4359, 849.3773, 861.8681, 890.07324
1573081480.943000, /eeg, 853.8095, 853.8095, 850.989, 866.30035, 854.61536
1573081480.944000, /eeg, 855.42126, 855.0183, 846.1539, 852.1978, 846.9597
1573081480.947000, /eeg, 844.1392, 853.8095, 846.55676, 842.52747, 873.5531
1573081480.947000, /eeg, 848.97437, 853.00366, 851.79486, 853.00366, 856.2271
1573081480.948000, /eeg, 859.0476, 852.6007, 850.18317, 863.8828, 826.0073
1573081480.950000, /eeg, 859.0476, 851.79486, 853.00366, 866.30035, 819.5604
1573081480.950000, /eeg, 851.79486, 852.1978, 846.9597, 854.61536, 859.45056
1573081480.951000, /eeg, 856.63007, 853.00366, 846.55676, 840.9158, 854.21246
```

pandas will produce this error:

```
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 6, saw 7
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want the resulting data structure to look like?  A dataframe of some sort?  How many columns?  Something else?

Comment: I can imagine reading the file line by line, spltting on ',', assigning the first two elements to a list, and keeping the rest as a nested list.  In other words a nested list structure can handle it.  But, where do you want to go from there?  What do you intend to do with the data?

Comment: I would like it to be imported into a data frame.

Comment: The data is used for signal/spectral analysis.  Up to now I've only had to process flat CSV files, this format change has me wondering about the best way to do this.  The file sizes get large but pandas is so fast, I really love using it.  Surely other people have encountered this, that's why I was thinking that pandas or numpy might already have a solution.

Comment: Read it with `df = pd.read_csv('myFile.csv', header=None)`. Later you can rename the columns with `df.columns = ['time', 'name', 'data1', 'data2', ... 'data_max']`

Comment: @Aryerez  That doesn't work. 


`df = pd.read_csv(fname, header=None, nrows=1000)
print("Data columns", df.columns)`


Produces:


`pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 8, saw 6`

Comment: @DebraGracePeri Try adding `engine=‘python’` as a parameter to the `read_csv()`

Comment: @Aryerez The same is error is produced.

Comment: Parsing rows of different lengths works fine in latest pandas using the `read_csv` function. The above sample code reads just fine. If you are having problems with other rows you should try to locate the bad row, and if you cannot figure it out, edit the question to include the bad row.

Comment: @hirolau I was hoping to not have to hard code the conversion, it doesn't seem to me to be a rare problem so I'm assuming others have a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear exactly what you want. Good that you have provided an example output, but it would be so much easier if it was the actault expected output from your input.

Give when I understand, the easiest way would be to loop each type, find how many columns they uses, create many frames, and finally concat them. Like this:

```
# Using pandas:
max_number_of_columns = pandas.read_csv('test.txt', sep='|', header=None)[0].str.count(',').max()
# or just hardcoded:
max_number_of_columns = 10

base = pandas.read_csv('test.txt', header=None, names=list(range(max_number_of_columns)))
base.columns =  ['time','datatype'] + list(base.columns[2:])

results = [base.iloc[:,:2]]
for datatype in base['datatype'].unique():
    group = base[base['datatype']==datatype].iloc[:,2:].dropna(how='all', axis=1) 
    group.columns = [f"{datatype}_{x}" for x in range(len(group.columns))]
    results.append(group)

final = pandas.concat(results, axis=1)
```

Edit: Fix for when first row contains less columns than later rows.

Comment: pandas fails while reading the CSV file using pandas.read_csv().

Traceback (most recent call last):
<snip>
pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 937, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2132, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 3, saw 7

Comment: If you paste your example data above in a text file and try to parse that, does that work for you?

Comment: Yes, but I found an issue with pandas read_csv() method. If the number of fields in the first line is shorter than and subsequent lines pandas fails.  I don't know how to add code/file data to comments so I'll add to the list of answers.  (sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow)

Comment: OMG!  I think this works!  

And it's so much faster than what I was coding up.  I really love pandas.  I'm pretty sure this is the fix, need to test a little more.  

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could normalize a CSV, and create a no error CSV using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) in this way:

```
mlr --csv --implicit-csv-header unsparsify \
then rename 1,one,2,two \
then reshape -r "[0-9]" -o item,value \
then filter -x -S '$value==""' \
then put '$item=fmtnum(($item-2),"%03d");$item=$two."_".$item' \
then cut -x -f two then sort -f item -n one \
then reshape -s item,value \
then unsparsify input.csv >output.csv
```

And you will have CSV like this, that you will able to import

```
one               /eeg_001  /eeg_002  /eeg_003  /eeg_004  /eeg_005  /elements/alpha_absolute_001 /elements/beta_absolute_001 /elements/delta_absolute_001 /elements/gamma_absolute_001 /elements/theta_absolute_001
1573081480.942000 844.1392  857.4359  849.3773  861.8681  890.07324 -                            -                           -                            -                            -
1573081480.943000 853.8095  853.8095  850.989   866.30035 854.61536 -                            -                           -                            -                            -
1573081480.944000 855.42126 855.0183  846.1539  852.1978  846.9597  -                            -                           -                            -                            -
1573081480.947000 848.97437 853.00366 851.79486 853.00366 856.2271  -                            -                           -                            -                            -
1573081480.948000 859.0476  852.6007  850.18317 863.8828  826.0073  -                            -                           -                            -                            -
1573081480.950000 851.79486 852.1978  846.9597  854.61536 859.45056 -                            -                           -                            -                            -
1573081480.951000 856.63007 853.00366 846.55676 840.9158  854.21246 -                            -                           -                            -                            -
1573081480.960000 -         -         -         -         -         0.48463312                   0.061746284                 -                            -                            -
1573081480.961000 -         -         -         -         -         -                            -                           0.7263172                    0.7263172                    0.7263172
```

Comment: That's a really helpful tool!  But, I'm not sure if I've been clear.  Here's an example of what the result should look like:

Comment: `time, eeg_0, eeg_1, eeg_2, eeg_3, delta, theta, alpha, beta, gamma
1573081480.942000, 844.1392, 857.4359, 849.3773, 861.8681,,,,,
1573081480.947000, 844.1392, 853.8095, 846.55676, 842.52747, 873.5531,,,,,
1573081480.947000, 848.97437, 853.00366, 851.79486, 853.00366, 856.2271,,,,,
1573081480.948000, 859.0476, 852.6007, 850.18317, 863.8828, 826.0073,,,,,
1573081480.960000,,,,,,,0.48463312,,
1573081480.960000,,,,,,,,0.061746284,
1573081480.961000,,,,,0.7263172,,,,
1573081480.961000,,,,,0.52961296,,,
1573081480.962000,,,,,,,,-0.26484978
`

Comment: @DebraGracePeri could you edit your question and add the desired output in it?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I just did!  I'm new to stackoverflow and am just learning the way to format questions/answers.

Comment: That's creating multiple columns for the same data:

/elements/alpha_absolute_1    
/elements/alpha_absolute_2   
/elements/alpha_absolute_3

Comment: I've edited the question to show the code that seems to be working but is terribly slow.

Comment: @DebraGracePeri I have edit my reply and there are no more multiple columns for the same data. Is it a right output now?

Comment: No, it still creates multiple fields.  For example: /eeg_1, /eeg_2, /eeg_3, /eeg_4, /eeg_5, /eeg_6, /eeg_7, /eeg_8.  There should only be 5 eeg fields.  The longer the file, the more eeg_* fields are created.  Plus, it's really slow. The pandas solution finished a 90MB file in 0m36.268s, the mlr version is still running after 10 minutes.  I believe the pandas solution above is the quickest, most efficient and elegant.  Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @DebraGracePeri Finally I have understood (I hope) what you want. Unfortunately you have already choose the right reply :( , but please test once again my script (I have edited again).

Comment: That works better but the field names don't start at 0 or 1.  Thank you for the help but I think the pandas solution works the best.

/eeg_003, /eeg_004, /eeg_005, /eeg_006, /eeg_007

Comment: @DebraGracePeri to start the numbering from one is easy, I have done. A last question: did you try it? Is it fast? Thank you

Comment: Hello, yes I did try it but unfortunately it's very slow.  I refer to use the pandas method, it's faster and is better suited for large data sets.